# How do I change background color of bottom tabs when tab has stack on it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

Currently I have set the background color in the tab navigator.

```
<Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => <CustomBottomTab {...props} />}
      screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
      ...
      tabBarStyle: 
          {
            display: 'flex',
            backgroundColor: colors.black_015
          },
```

But this only works on the tabs that doesn't have a stack on them and their color changes correctly to darker color and the tabs with the stacks their color is white or white with bit of gray.

I have tried to do following in my home stack

```
const HomeStack = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const route = useRoute()

useEffect(() => {

    const tabShownRoutes = [
      'HomeScreen',
    ]

    if (tabShownRoutes.includes(getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route))) {
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.black_015 } })
    }

  }, [navigation, route])
```

This works but only if I navigate to another screen in that stack.

Before (After opening application)

[image]

And after when going to one of the screens in the stack.

[image]

How can I make it to stay black color?

Comment: if (tabShownRoutes.includes(getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route))) {
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.black_015 } })
    } 

have you checked with setting color with else part..